# Drupal - White Screen of Death after updates (and login page returning 403 error)

Tags: drupal, wsod

I have just updated a site that is using Drupal and have now experienced the horrible WSOD.

I have searched through Google looking for any sort of solution/error log to help me find and fix the issue but nothing has worked.  I have tried adding in the 'display errors' code in the `index.php` file and looked at the `error_log` file in the public directory and nothing.

I can not login to the admin page and check any modules as the login page for this is returning a 403 error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the updated modules? Did you run `update.php` script?!

Comment: And what's the Drupal version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to Apache Error log. You will exact error messages there.
The log file's location is different for different OS and versions.

e.g httpd/log/error.log

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Drupal registry is broken.
Fix this using the registry_rebuild script (this is no module!)

> There are times in Drupal 7 when the registry gets hopelessly hosed and you need to rebuild the registry (a list of PHP classes and the files they go with). Sometimes, though, you can't do this regular cache-clear activity because some class is required when the system is trying to bootstrap.
>
> You might get something like:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'EntityAPIControllerExportable' not found in ...sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.core.inc on line 11`

> If this happens when you're trying to run update.php, and happens when you're trying to clear your cache, well, you have some trouble. That's what Registry Rebuild is for.
>
> It also may happen that you've moved some module that Drupal requires to bootstrap, and you get a horrible error. Registry Rebuild will also rebuild the system table to get the modules in the right place so you can bootstrap.

You will need PHP-CLI or drush to run this.

https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild